# JAVA BoofCV method's alternative for Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, image-stitching, boofcv

I have been using [Boof CV](http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) libary for **Image Stitching** and followed [this](http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Example_Image_Stitching).

I have to convert some **Data types** and **methods** to be acceptable in android.

I want an equivalent of this in Android BoofCV

```
T inputA = ConvertBufferedImage.convertFromSingle(imageA, null, imageType);
```

Where **imageA** is a bitmap image.

Comment: how did you manage to import `BufferedImage`? I'm also following the same example but my IDE complaints that `BufferedImage` is not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily I found the solution

```
T inputA=ConvertBitmap.bitmapToGray(imageA,null,imageType,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ConvertBitmap.  It contains all the functions you need.